# jQuery to retrieve id and modify its text

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a table generated by php and implementing a modal to allow user to change the text generated by variable `$l_id`; I have a link class "eloc" that show's the modal div section. I intercept the form submit id "renameLocation" and process the input and disable the default submit action. I want to modify show the new text renamed by the user.

I have this php code which repeated by iterating an array, the iteration id is `$l`

```
$id_l="\"location_".$l."\"";
echo "<table class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\">";
echo "<tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td id=\"".$id_l."\" class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\">Location: ".$row['location']."</td></tr>";
```

Then I have a div:

```
<div id="modal_location" class="modal_prompt">      
    <div class="modal_prompt-ct">           
        <div class="modal_prompt-header">
            <h2>Rename Location</h2>
            <a class="modal_close" href="#"></a>            
        </div>

        <form id="renameLocation">
            <div class="txt-dpy">
                <span id="mlocation_name"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="txt-fld">
                <label for="">Change to</label> 
                <input id="newLocation" name="" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="btn-fld">
                <button type="submit">Save &raquo;</button>
            </div>          
        </form>         
    </div>  
</div>
```

How to modify the text for the generated $l_id?

```
$("#renameLocation").submit(function(e) 
{
    $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
    $("#modal_location").css({"display" : "none" })
    // How to modify the text of "$l_id"?
    return false; //do not submit form the normal way        
});
```

Many thanks.

Comment: So is there more than one text they can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is ambiguous. It sounds like you have more than one text to edit.

You need a way to tell JS which location to update so add a global variable. It's not usual way you'd do this but it should be okay.

Add data to the element

```
$id_l="\"location_".$l."\"";
echo "<table class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\">";
echo "<tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\" 
    data-location=\"".$l."\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td id=\"".$id_l."\" class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\">Location: ".$row['location']."</td></tr>";
```

set this at the top of your js

```
var selectedlocation=0;
```

bind clicking the edit link to set selectedlocation

```
$('.eloc').on('click', function(){
    selectedlocation=$(this).data('location');
});
```

use the var in your code

```
$("#renameLocation").submit(function(e) 
{
    var location=$(this).data('location');
    $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
    $("#modal_location").css({"display" : "none" })
    $('#location_'+selectedlocation).text();
    e.preventDefault(); //return false; //do not submit form the normal way        
});
```

**Here's another way**

Forget the global variable.

Add a hidden form field

```
<form id="renameLocation">
    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="" id="renameLocation_location"/>
```

Put the value in that

```
$('.eloc').on('click', function(){
    $('#renameLocation_location').val($(this).data('location'));
});
```

And use that.

```
$('#location_'+ $('#renameLocation_location').val() ).text();
```

The way you have provided it, the modal is totally independant to the links you need something to set somewhere to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, correct I have more than one text to edit. I can do something suggested by you, I am looking at jQuery Tree Traversal methods like .parent, .find etc and see if I can use something to locate the class "location" and modify it. I have more php experience than java/jquery at this moment.

Comment: The problem you have is the form is inside a modal which is separate to the link that's opening it. You don't need to `.find()` anything when you know where you put it.

Comment: If you provide the modal JS that is triggered when .eloc is clicked that may be able to be altered for it to be a little slicker.

Comment: I have nearly 20 years experience, I can tell you you're wasting your time looking at trying to traverse to an element that opens a modal from a form within that modal. What you know is which link you clicked to open it. Use it.

Comment: OK, I get the idea behind the code. Let me try and feedback later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this-

```
$("#<?php echo $l_id?>").html("Your updated text here");
```

Comment: that doesn't make sense. If it's being outputted in PHP just output the text in the div.

Comment: The $l_id was generated to display in html such as "location1", "location2". The modal is a form class id renameLocation with text input to capture the text user want to rename. I don't think the above code does that purpose.